# 23.04: how to add new folder to Nautilus window using GUI

Tags: nautilus

Since upgrading to 23.04 there is no longer the option to add a new folder/directory or file under the "three lines" menu in the top right of the Nautilus window. The are only options for a new window or a new tab there, The only way I have found to add a new directory is to use Ctrl + Shift + N. How can I get the old mouse driven menu back?

Answer (score 4):

I have discovered that if I move the pointer to the right hand side of the window just before the slider and at the side of the entries, and then right click the new folder option appears.
[image]

I would expect improvements to be made in Nautilus as this is one of the most common requirements of a file manager and shouldn't be so difficult to find and use.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Nautilus GUI design is rather poor, unintuitive and (unfortunately) becoming worse with each version. Please note that there is a veeeery narrow horizontal space also between two file entries. I updated my answer too.

Comment: That wouldn't be a factor if you used the grid view option.

Comment: @graham Why should I be forced to use the grid view? What's the point of offering a choice of two views and then making one of the two choices unusable?

Comment: the ability to toggle between the two views is no big deal when you need to.

Comment: It should be simple to add a new folder in a file manager whichever view you prefer! And the method should be clearly documented and preferably should not change with every new release of the OS

Answer (score 3):

You have at least four options:

1. Right click onto an empty area while you are in the folder you want to create new sub-folder into and select **New Folder...**. However, when that folder is full of files, you cannot easily reach to this right-click menu. Use the other options.
2. If the above option cannot be easily used, note that there is a very narrow area between two file entries as shown on the image below. You can right click on that tiny area and select  **New Folder...**:

[image]

3. Use the "three dot" (**⋮**) menu in the right of the file location input box and select **New Folder...**:

[image]

This option will only be available when the *dconf* value for **/ org / gnome / nautilus / preferences / always-use-location-entry** is set to default (False). As @vanadium pointed out, this should be considered as a bug!

4. Use keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>  as a last resort.

Comment: There is no "three dot" menu in the file location input box on my 23.04 system. However I have discovered if I go as far to the right hand side of the window, at the side of the entries, and right click the new folder option appears.

Comment: /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/always-use-location-entry is already set to true.

Comment: That is why you do not see the "current folder" menu, i.e., the three dots. Probably, it should also be in view when you keep the location entry on. This is worthy filing as an issue.

Comment: FedKad changed his advice from true to false. I have tried it as false and yes, the three dots appear, but I cannot work with this setting as I often copy and paste locations into the terminal.

Comment: Yes, that is what I said in the comment, and what Fedkad now also accounted for in his answer. We both agree with you that the current folder menu should remain available also when the location bar is in use, but it currently is not.